# Optional foreign key with django?

Tags: django, sqlite, foreign-keys, option-type

In my models.py, I want to have an optional field to a foreign key. I tried this:

```
field = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

I am getting this error:

```
model.mymodel_id may not be NULL
```

I am using sqlite. In case it is helpful, here is the exception location:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 200
```

Comment: Have you sync'd your db?

Answer (score 5):

If it was previously not null and you synced it before then resyncing won't change it. Either drop the table, use a migration tool such as South, or alter the column in SQL directly.

Comment: i removed sqlite database file, and synced, but i still have the same problem. :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it has to be both `null=True` and `blank=True`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on this one, but I think you need to lose the "default=None" and do a reset/syncdb. The default overrides the null/blank info. I.e. if you give a blank in the admin it will store None (whose representation may vary from DB to DB). I would need to look at the code/docs to be more certain.

Comment: I don't know if losing the default=None will fix this but I think you should remove it either way. (Could be wrong though.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and drilled down to the table creation process itself (because the problems arise in doing tests too.)

For a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

the generated sql (with `./manage.py sql`) is:

```
CREATE TABLE `app_mymodel` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `owner_id` integer
)
ALTER TABLE `app_mymodel` ADD CONSTRAINT `owner_id_refs_id_34553282` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`);
```

So it seems that the table itself allows Null values, but the FK constraint at the DB level is in fact constraining the values to be actual refences, so no NULL values...

Is it a bug in Django?

**EDIT:** It turns out that a table created with the former command **will** accept NULL values in the FK column, and in fact has `DEFAULT NULL` on the column spec when written out with `SHOW CREATE TABLE app_mymodel;`. It's strange, but I can't replicate the errors now.